# R algorithm for deleting rows with artefacts

Tags: r, algorithm, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I'm analyzing DEM data of rivers with R and need assistance with the data processing. The DEM data include many artifacts, where the river longitudinal profile goes slightly uphill, which is in fact nonsense. So I would like to have an algorithm to delete all rows from the data set where the Z value (elevation) is higher than the predecessor. To explain it better, just look at the following data rows:

```
*data.frame*

ID Z

1  105.2

2  105.4

3  105.3

4  105.1

5  105.1

6  105.2

7  104.9
```

I would like to delete rows 2, 3 and 6 from the list. I wrote the following code but it doesn't work:

```
i <- *data.frame*[1,2]
for (n in *data.frame*[,2]) {if(n-i>0) *data.frame*[i,2]=0 else i <- n}
```

I would be very appreciated if anybody can help.

Comment: You don't need a loop: `DF[c(TRUE, diff(DF$Z) > 0),]` (untested because there is no reproducible example)

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working well, even when corrected to: DF[c(TRUE, diff(DF$Z) <= 0,]. It deletes rows 2 and 6, but row 3 is still extant. While I could do this procedure again, this isn't very comfortable, because the original dataset has up to 100,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you want to recursively remove values until there are no increasing values. It would be easiest to simply use a `while` loop:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "ID Z
                 1  105.2
                 2  105.4
                 3  105.3
                 4  105.1
                 5  105.1
                 6  105.2
                 7  104.9", header = TRUE)

while(any(diff(DF$Z) > 0)) DF <- DF[c(TRUE, diff(DF$Z) <= 0),]
#  ID     Z
#1  1 105.2
#4  4 105.1
#5  5 105.1
#7  7 104.9
```

Test yourself, if this is sufficiently efficient.

I would also like to comment on your whole idea of data cleaning here. I find it very dubious. How do you now that there is no error in the values that don't increase? You might remove perfectly valid values because there is an error in a (strongly) decreasing value.

Comment: The data cleaning maybe sound curious, but is necessary and correct. The DEM data came from LiDAR measurements with a high resolution, so you have bridges, stones or even waves, which produce artefacts within the river. In this step I want to exclude all these values to get a longitudinal river profile, where the water flows continuously downstream.

Comment: @jan going off-topic, how do you know your starting point is correct? you could be starting at some unwanted artefact (per your definition) without knowing it.

Comment: @Aramis7d: This is correct. But it is not very problematic, because the rivers I work on are 20 to 100 km long and I use DEM raster cells with 2 m width. So the point datasets along the river longitudal profile have many many points. Therefore, the starting point can easily excluded if necessary.